# Drawing the Peano curve

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, graphical-output, geometry, fractal

### Introduction

In geometry, the [Peano curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve) is the first example of a space-filling curve to be discovered, by Giuseppe Peano in 1890. Peano's curve is a surjective, continuous function from the unit interval onto the unit square, however it is not injective. Peano was motivated by an earlier result of Georg Cantor that these two sets have the same cardinality. Because of this example, some authors use the phrase "Peano curve" to refer more generally to any space-filling curve.

### Challenge

The program takes an input which is an integer `n`, and outputs a drawing representing the `n`th iteration of the Peano curve, starting from the sideways 2 shown in the leftmost part of this image:
[image: Three iterations of the Peano curve]

### Input

An integer `n` giving the iteration number of the Peano curve.
Optional, additional input is described in the bonuses section.

### Output

A drawing of the `n`th iteration of the Peano curve. The drawing can be both ASCII art or a "real" drawing, whichever is easiest or shortest.

### Rules

- The input and output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963) (choose the most appropriate format for your language/solution).
- No need to handle **negative** values or **invalid input**
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

### Bonuses

Since this shouldn't be a walk in the park (at least in most languages I can think of), bonus points are awarded for the following:

- -100 bytes if your code generates a gif of the construction of the Peano curves up to `n`.
- -100 bytes if your code draws a space-filling curve for any rectangular shape (the Peano curve only works for squares, obviously). You can assume that the input then takes on the form `n l w` where `n` has the same meaning as before (the number of the iteration), but where `l` and `w` become the length and width of the rectangle in which to draw the curve. If `l == w`, this becomes the regular Peano curve.

Negative scores are allowed (but are they possible...).

### Edit

Please include the output of your program in the solution for `n == 3 (l == w == 1)`.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :) This, at a glance, looks like a nice first challenge. Although it feels familiar, I think the challenge I might be thinking of was an ASCII art one. Note, though, that we strongly discourage bonuses and that there will be golfing languages that can achieve this in less than 100 bytes. Also, and most importantly, you need a winning criterion. Given that your bonuses subtract bytes from a solution's score, I suspect you intend this to be [tag:code-golf].

Comment: I think you're probably confusing it with either a question about Hilbert curves, which are sort of an easier version of Peano curves, or one of the many questions about fractals, mainly the Koch snowflake and Sierpinski carpet. As for the bonuses, I seriously doubt that there would be golfing languages that can do this in less than 100 bytes... And my winning criterion is included, it's the last point in the "Rules" section :).

Comment: Have you seen golfing languages on this site? I’m willing to bet Canvas can do it in less than 50.

Comment: Oh, I could well be thinking of a challenge about a different (but maybe similar looking pattern), which is why I didn't VTC this as a dupe - that and my vote is a hammer, so I avoid using it unless I'm 100% sure a challenge is a dupe. And apologies for missing the winning criterion; my brain must have trained itself to gloss over the boilerplate rules section of a challenge! I was looking for the winning condition in the tags.

Comment: I added the criterion to the tags, and removed one of the less interesting ones ;). I know the question itself shouldn't be that hard to solve, but I doubt the golfing languages can generate gifs easily.
I could remove the bonuses, but then how do I motivate people to still try to complete those tasks?

Comment: Our mere presence on this SE is motivation enough for us to complete challenges! ;)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the bonuses are a good idea, especially since there _at least_ two animation-capable ASCII-art focused golflangs

Comment: Oh also what would `n` be used for if `l` and `w` are _also_ inputs??????????? And would the Peano curve be a special case - it's not the only spacefilling curve, so some algorithms may have to specialcase it

Comment: Also, what stops anyone from making a trivial spacefilling curve (just zigzagging back and forth) for non-square dimensions

Comment: [Bonuses in code golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/39328) is one of the most agreed-upon things to avoid when writing challenges. I suggest you remove them and decide which is to be the canonical version of the challenge.

Comment: Is that OK if the output is mirrored horizontally and/or vertically?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, that's alright

Comment: Even if you're going to keep the bonises, please address [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176168/drawing-the-peano-curve#comment424029_176168). Which curve sd be used for retangulr outpt?

Comment: A continuous space-filling curve which looks like the Peano curve while covering the rectangle. If it does this, it's acceptable output.

Comment: @ASCII-only A true "space filling curve" is the continuous function that is the *limit* of such drawings (its own drawing would just be a solid black rectangle), and you cannot actually get a continuous function in the limit from zigzagging.

Comment: Are we allowed to draw it upside down?

Comment: Sure! @LiefdeWen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Mathematica, score 60 - 100 - 100 = -140

```
Graphics[PeanoCurve@a~Reverse~3~Scale~#2]~Animate~{a,1,#,1}&
```

Pure function. Takes `n` and `{l, w}` (width and height) as input, and gives an animated graphic as output. It first creates a *n*th order Peano curve with `PeanoCurve`. Since the *l* = *w* case still needs to create a Peano curve, we flip the expression at level 3, similar to [DavidC's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176175); for *l* ≠ *w*, we just `Scale` the curve to the rectangle. This curve will still be space-filling, satisfying the second bonus. For the first bonus, we just `Animate` it over all sizes. Note that OP suggested that this was sufficiently different from DavidC's to warrant its own answer. The result for *n* = 3, *l* = *w* = 1 is as follows:

[image]

Comment: very nice! (with proper orientation too)

Answer (score 13):

## [GFA Basic 3.51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFA_BASIC) (Atari ST), <s>156</s> <s>134</s> 124 bytes

A manually edited listing in .LST format. All lines end with `CR`, including the last one.

```
PRO f(n)
DR "MA0,199"
p(n,90)
RET
PRO p(n,a)
I n
n=n-.5
DR "RT",a
p(n,-a)
DR "FD4"
p(n,a)
DR "FD4"
p(n,-a)
DR "LT",a
EN
RET
```

#### Expanded and commented

```
PROCEDURE f(n)      ! main procedure, taking the number 'n' of iterations
  DRAW "MA0,199"    !   move the pen to absolute position (0, 199)
  p(n,90)           !   initial call to 'p' with 'a' = +90
RETURN              ! end of procedure
PROCEDURE p(n,a)    ! recursive procedure taking 'n' and the angle 'a'
  IF n              !   if 'n' is not equal to 0:
    n=n-0.5         !     subtract 0.5 from 'n'
    DRAW "RT",a     !     right turn of 'a' degrees
    p(n,-a)         !     recursive call with '-a'
    DRAW "FD4"      !     move the pen 4 pixels forward
    p(n,a)          !     recursive call with 'a'
    DRAW "FD4"      !     move the pen 4 pixels forward
    p(n,-a)         !     recursive call with '-a'
    DRAW "LT",a     !     left turn of 'a' degrees
  ENDIF             !   end
RETURN              ! end of procedure
```

#### Example output

[image: peano-gfa]

Answer (score 10):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 117 bytes

```perl6
{map ->\y{|map {(((++$+y)%2+$++)%3**(y+$^v,*/3...*%3)??$^s[$++%2]!!'│')xx$_*3},<┌ ┐>,$_,<└ ┘>,1},^$_}o*R**3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYm7DoIwAEV3v6KSVvqyRmpc1PIPrmIbBkk08ggkhgZZnB0cOvh9/EgFl3vuyaku9X3rcwsWGTj4Lk8rsFSJ7Z7T6zDGjEFmCYpGMIIkpdgyqB@crqQQgiJJ4hjq5jRmFJ3n83Bwr5C0LTRU9nw/uDcY3EdxaCZxo3wVX/dcQ9OX9Eip9LtZk1qQYWiIUuJWXov/4CApAsLBBJCVNdAb/wM)

0-indexed. Returns a 2D array of Unicode characters. The basic idea is that for lower rows, the expression

```perl6
(x + (x+y)%2) % (3 ** trailing_zeros_in_base3(3*(y+1)))
```

yields the pattern

```perl6
|....||....||....||....||..  % 3
..||....||....||....||....|  % 3
|................||........  % 9
..||....||....||....||....|  % 3
|....||....||....||....||..  % 3
........||................|  % 9
|....||....||....||....||..  % 3
..||....||....||....||....|  % 3
|..........................  % 27
```

For upper rows, the expression is

```perl6
(x + (x+y+1)%2) % (3 ** trailing_zeros_in_base3(3*(y+3**n)))
```

#### Explanation

```perl6
{ ... }o*R**3  # Feed $_ = 3^n into block

map ->\y{ ... },^$_  # Map y = 0..3^n-1

|map { ... },<┌ ┐>,$_,<└ ┘>,1  # Map pairs (('┌','┐'),3^n) for upper rows
                               # and (('└','┘'),1) for lower rows.
                               # Block takes items as s and v

( ... )xx$_*3  # Evaluate 3^(n+1) times, returning a list

 (++$+y)%2  # (x+y+1)%2 for upper rows, (x+y)%2 for lower rows
(         +$++)  # Add x
                   (y+$^v,*/3...*%3)  # Count trailing zeros of 3*(y+v) in base 3
                3**  # nth power of 3
               %  # Modulo
??$^s[$++%2]  # If there's a remainder yield chars in s alternately
!!'│'         # otherwise yield '│'
```

Answer (score 7):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>37</s> <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
{+y,(|'y:x,,~>+x),x}/1,&2*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/Nqlq7UkejRr3SqkJHp85Ou0JTp6JW31BHzUjrf5qCERdXgoGVkoKykoOOvoaOkpKmjr5VmrqiyX8A)

returns a boolean matrix

`|'y` is syntax specific to ngn/k. other dialects require a `:` to make an each-ed verb monadic: `|:'y`

Comment: To make the output more beautiful, highlight all occurences of `1 ` (if supported by your browser)

Comment: @user202729 done - in the footer so it don't affect the byte count

Answer (score 5):

## Wolfram Language <s>83</s> 36 bytes, (possibly -48 bytes with bonus)

As of version 11.1, `PeanoCurve` is a built-in.

My original, clumsy submission wasted many bytes on `GeometricTransformation` and `ReflectionTransform.`

This much reduced version was suggested by **alephalpha**.
`Reverse` was required to orient the output properly.

```
Graphics[Reverse/@#&/@PeanoCurve@#]&
```

**Example 36 bytes**

```
Graphics[Reverse/@#&/@PeanoCurve@#]&[3]
```

[image: Peano curve]

---

### Bonus

If this qualifies for the 100 pt bonus, it weighs in at 52 - 100 = -48
The code `[5]` was not counted, only the pure function.

```
Table[Graphics[Reverse/@#&/@PeanoCurve@#]&@k{k,#}&[5]
```

[image: sequence]

Comment: `Graphics[Reverse/@#&/@PeanoCurve@#]&`

Comment: It feels a bit like cheating to have a function which calculates the Peano curve by itself, but I'll take it as accepted answer since it's pretty impressive nonetheless ;).
@LegionMammal978 I think you deserve to post your own answer, I'd argue that it's different enough to warrant accepting it as winning answer.

Answer (score 5):

## HTML+SVG+JS, <s>224</s> 213 bytes

The output is mirrored horizontally.

```javascript
n=>document.write(`<svg width=${w=3**n*9} height=${w}><path d="M1 ${(p=(n,z)=>n--&&(p(n,-z,a(a(p(n,-z,d+=z)),p(n,z))),d-=z))(n*2,r=d=x=y=1,a=_=>r+=`L${x+=~-(d&=3)%2*9} ${y+=(2-d)%2*9}`)&&r}"fill=#fff stroke=red>`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY9BboMwAATvfYWVUmQDjhRyapTlBe0bioVtcEpsZNyQgOjXaUiV285qpdWcxEX0lTdd4NZJtWgsFoV01c9Z2bAdvAmKlsf@UpPByNAgmgbsk8Qm7zNplKmbsFZzcexEaIjE5nNHool2oDYbGQrLeRzT7k58zAQVzyhTjIxl3WN2D5KvTG2SZx4SV9ywywS@UPgU5Uc0XVP8cipj7Nlbvr5H0y0Fzbn855LFsZ832rQtXrXWpA/efSt4JYuSLU8lAjKRh9aBVM72rlXb1tVkftE0Z8sf) (prints the HTML)

```js
(
n=>document.write(`<svg width=${w=3**n*9} height=${w}><path d="M1 ${(p=(n,z)=>n--&&(p(n,-z,a(a(p(n,-z,d+=z)),p(n,z))),d-=z))(n*2,r=d=x=y=1,a=_=>r+=`L${x+=~-(d&=3)%2*9} ${y+=(2-d)%2*9}`)&&r}"fill=#fff stroke=red>`)
)(3)
```

Answer (score 4):

## BBC BASIC, 142 ASCII characters (130 bytes tokenised)

Download interpreter at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/download.html

```
I.m:q=FNh(m,8,8,0)END
DEFFNh(n,x,y,i)
IFn F.i=0TO8q=FNh(n-1,x-i MOD3MOD2*2*x,y-i DIV3MOD2*2*y,i)DRAWBY(1AND36/2^i)*x,y*(12653/3^i MOD3-1)N.
=0
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
∩▐j>♣←╙~◘∩╗╢\a╘─Ràô
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=efde6a3e051bd37e08efbbb65c61d4c4528593&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4&a=1&m=2)

Output for 3:

```
███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ █
█ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███
█         █ █         █ █         █ █         █ █    
█ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███
███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █
    █ █         █ █         █ █         █ █         █
███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █
█ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ ███ ███
█                                 █ █                
█ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ ███ ███
███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █
    █ █         █ █         █ █         █ █         █
███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █
█ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███
█         █ █         █ █         █ █         █ █    
█ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███
███ ███ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ █
                █ █                                 █
███ ███ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ █
█ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███
█         █ █         █ █         █ █         █ █    
█ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███
███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █
    █ █         █ █         █ █         █ █         █
███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ ███ ███ █
█ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███ ███
```

Answer (score 3):

### Logo, 89 bytes

```
to p:n:a
if:n>0[rt:a
p:n-1 0-:a
fw 5
p:n-1:a
fw 5
p:n-1 0-:a
lt:a]end
to f:n
p:n*2 90
end
```

Port of @Arnauld's Atari BASIC answer. To use, do something like [this](http://logo.twentygototen.org/56yMrISL):

```
reset
f 3
```

Comment: Sadly the link no longer works but you can paste the code into [this online interpreter](https://rmmh.github.io/papert/static/).